# Java inyectar servicio externo

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Estoy utilizando en el pom de mi aplicación este proyecto:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.girotan.notification</groupId>
    <artifactId>notification-service-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Dentro de un servicio utilizo una clase @Service del proyecto mencionado `NotificationRestClient`, así:

```
void sendEmailNotificationMessage(ApiEmailNotification apiEmailNotification) throws BusinessException {

    NotificationEnvelope notificationEnvelope = new NotificationEnvelope();
    notificationEnvelope.setType(ApiNotificationType.EMAIL);
    notificationEnvelope.setNotification(apiEmailNotification);

    NotificationRestClient restClient = new NotificationRestClient();
    restClient.send(notificationEnvelope);
}
```

Sin embargo esto me parece poco elegante, estoy utilizando spring. ¿Existe una forma de inyectar `NotificationRestClient restClient` y no instanciarlo como un objeto?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define un nuevo *bean* en tu clase de configuración:

```
@Configuration
public class PompousConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public NotificationRestClient getNotificationRestClient() {
        return new NotificationRestClient();
    }

}
```

E *inyéctalo* de la siguiente manera:

```
@Autowired
private NotificationRestClient restClient;

void sendEmailNotificationMessage(ApiEmailNotification apiEmailNotification) 
        throws BusinessException {

    NotificationEnvelope notificationEnvelope = new NotificationEnvelope();
    notificationEnvelope.setType(ApiNotificationType.EMAIL);
    notificationEnvelope.setNotification(apiEmailNotification);

    restClient.send(notificationEnvelope);
}
```

<sub>NOTA: Puedes cambiar el *ámbito* de tu *bean* en caso de que `NotificationRestClient` sea *thread-safe*.</sub>